# How to allow characters other than letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens in a Django SlugField

Tags: django

Wikipedia slugs sometimes contain characters other than letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens such as apostrophes or commas. For example [Martha's_Vineyard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martha%27s_Vineyard)

In my Django app I am storing Wikipedia slugs in my model which have been pre-populated from a Wikipedia extract. I use the Wikipedia slug to generate slugs for my Django app's own webpages. I'd therefore like to use SlugField as the field type and have a model field definition of:-

`slug = models.SlugField(default=None,null=True,blank=True,max_length=255,unique=True)`

However as you would expect from the Django documentation this throws an error of 'Enter a valid “slug” consisting of letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens.' when there is an apostrophe or comma in the Wikipedia slug.

Adding allow_unicode=True did not seem to solve the issue:-

`slug = models.SlugField(default=None,null=True,blank=True,max_length=255,unique=True,allow_unicode=True,)`

ChatGPT suggested a custom slug validator as follows but the same error occurred and ChatGPT concluded 'It appears that Django's SlugField is stricter in its validation than I initially thought, and it may not accept commas (,) even with a custom validator':-

```
custom_slug_validator = RegexValidator(
    regex=r'^[a-zA-Z0-9'_-]+$',
    message="Enter a valid slug consisting of letters, numbers, commas, underscores, or hyphens.",
    code='invalid_slug'
)

class Route(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(
        default=None,
        allow_unicode=True,
        null=True,
        max_length=255,
        validators=[custom_slug_validator],  # Apply the custom slug validator
        help_text="Enter the Wikipedia slug with special characters (' - or _)",
    )
```

For now I have reverted to using CharField but suspect I am missing out on some benefits of SlugField. For example, I sometimes generate and store my own slugs in the field where no equivalent page exists in Wikipedia so the standard validation of SlugField has benefits. Can SlugField be customised to accept Wikipedia valid slugs ?

Comment: The idea of a `SlugField` is exactly that, to not allow all sorts of characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Wikipedia slugs sometimes contain characters other than letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens such as apostrophes or commas.

That's because these are *not* slugs. A limits the character space, this also ensures that if a person saves the file, the slug can act as a filename on (almost) any system. By adding all sorts of characters, that is no longer guaranteed.

But a `SlugField` is not very special, it is just a `CharField` with some "extras". We can see that in the [source code <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1dae65dc63ae84be5002c37b4ddae0b9220e8808/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2398-L2432):

> ```
> def __init__(
>     self, *args, max_length=50, db_index=True, allow_unicode=False, **kwargs
> ):
>     self.allow_unicode = allow_unicode
>     if self.allow_unicode:
>         self.default_validators = [validators.validate_unicode_slug]
>     super().__init__(*args, max_length=max_length, db_index=db_index, **kwargs)
> ```

It thus sets the `max_length=50` by default to `50`, and adds a `db_index=True`, and adds some validation and a custom form field. The max length is necessary since a lot of databases only index *short* strings, not long ones.

We thus can make our own custom field, or just work with a `CharField`:

```
class Route(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(
        default=None,
        db_index=True,
        null=True,
        max_length=50,
        validators=[custom_slug_validator],  # Apply the custom slug validator
        help_text="Enter the Wikipedia slug with special characters (' - or _)",
    )
```

you can also construct your own custom field, just like they did in Django to automatically set certain values, but a `SlugField` is thus, behind the curtains, just a `CharField` with some default values and validators.

Comment: It is the end part of the Wikipedia [Clean URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL) that I need to store and will reuse for the URLs of my own pages. It's not clear whether this end part is strictly speaking a slug, as the definition of slug tends to be language specific. Certainly the end part in Wikipedia can hold special characters such as ",", "'" or "(" and is not truncated to 50 characters, so the max-length and regex may need adjusting when using the solution above.